# Evaluating the series in simple way

Tags: sequences-and-series

Evaluate the series
 $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n +1}{n^2(n+1)^2}$$

I know to evaluate such series, I need to evaluate the limiting value when $n\to\infty$ of the partial sums of the series, but I am not able to find the final term whose limiting value need to be evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hinting:

$$\frac{2n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2}=\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{(n+1)^2}$$

So if you know $\;\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\;$ then you
ve finished. In fact, *even* if you don't know the limit you can telescope stuff above...

Comment: In case someone does not see this, it is just about writing $2n+1 = 2n+1 + n^2 - n^2$.

Comment: @Dark Thank you...but I think that if someone can't see this then he doesn't even have yet the level to understand this stuff...

Comment: @Joanpemo Is the value comes to be 1?

Comment: @kavitasahu Yes, the value of *your* series is $\;1\;$. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Hint we can write it as $\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ which is telescopic so only first and last term remain and as n tends to infinity last term becomes $0$. So value of limit is value of fist term which is $1$.